# How a program selects the transport layer protocl and how to get the source code of that

Tags: networking, application-layer

I need to analyse the source code of the process that selects the transport layer protocol when a data is sent over a network. I tried to find but still I haven't fount it. Can someone suggests me how to get this?

*At least If I can get the algorithm/ pseudocode that will also very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Transport layer is chosen by the application code, when creating a socket. It is not clear what you mean by "process".

Try grepping the app source code for the strings **SOCK_STREAM**, **SOCK_DGRAM**, **AF_INET** or **IPPROTO_TCP** for starters.

If you mean the Linux kernel, start in src/net/socket.c

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c

Comment: Thanks for the reply. could you tell me more specifically how to get those strings?(which file should I use in Linux) I'm new to this area.

Comment: @chathura2020 They aren't strings, they are manifest constants. As you haven't specified a programming language your question about where to get them isn't answerable.

Comment: @mrjoltcola Thanks for the link, I will use this as a starting point